# URL Parameter just disappears

Tags: php, wordpress, url-parameters

I'm creating a link that will add a URL parameter like so

```
<?php 
    $cat = 10;
    $childcats = get_categories('child_of=' . $cat);
    foreach ($childcats as $childcat) {
        $catName = $childcat->cat_name;
        $catID = $childcat->cat_ID;
?>
    <li <?php if($selectedCat == $catID){?> class="selected" <?php } ?> >
        <a href="<?php echo site_url('/lookbook/'); ?>?cat=<?php echo $catName ?>"><?php echo $catName ?></a>
    </li>
<?php
    }
?>
```

however when I click the link the page reloads without the appended parameter, which means my parameter reliant feature doesn't work.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Found this http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries "Custom Archives" but I can't seem to get it to work either, I've registered my query variable but it's still removing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use a different query argument than `cat`. I'm almost 100% sure that your problem is caused by the fact that `cat` is a built-in query argument in WordPress, so WordPress parses the argument and redirects you to the proper URL(if you are using pretty permalinks), or modifies the current query. For a list of arguments that `WP_Query` accepts(I'm not sure, if all of them can be set from the URL), see [Class Reference/WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

I would suggest that you use for instance `_cat` instead:

```
<?php 
    $cat = 10;
    $childcats = get_categories('child_of=' . $cat);
    foreach ($childcats as $childcat) {
        $catName = $childcat->cat_name;
        $catID = $childcat->cat_ID;
?>
    <li <?php if($selectedCat == $catID){?> class="selected" <?php } ?> >
        <a href="<?php echo site_url('/lookbook/'); ?>?_cat=<?php echo $catName ?>"><?php echo $catName ?></a>
    </li>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: That was close, in the end I defined my own http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries as "catagory_name"

Comment: I've never thought about using a custom query variable - good one :)

Answer (score 1):

Wheres $catName coming from?

One of these pages may help to populate $catName with what you need:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_name

or

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Comment: I've edited the question to show more code, I have the catName and it's returning a value, my href looks like this `href="http://www.mysite.com/lookbook/?cat=Women"`

Comment: Perhaps try ?category_name instead of ?cat

Comment: Just tried it but to no avail, this is so bizarre! Were you thinking that there might be a clash with the $cat variable in the php? On other pages of the site I can add "?cat=Men" to the end of the URL and it will stay put the page loads.

Comment: Odd!  The only other thing I can think of is to flush your rewrite rules by going to Settings -> Permalinks then clicking Save Changes.  Hope someone else comes along who can help!

Comment: Thanks for your help, still no luck! Since you mentioned rewrite rules I founds this http://tinyurl.com/btgvd63 seems like wordpress is removing the param, but there solution won't solve my problem. :(

Comment: Is it a fresh install, or do you have any plugins installed that may be rewriting the urls? (such as the SEO plugin mentioned in the above?).  You could also try this advice: http://dmjcomputerservices.com/blog/2010/05/20/passing-url-parameters-to-a-wordpress-page/